# Applying Format to a Dataset Column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DataSet`, I am binding my `GridView` with this `DataSet`. My `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true. One of the column that is returned by the `DataSet` has a `DateTime` value in it, I need only to get the date part of that and then bind the grid with the `DataSet`. I tried doing it this way, but that didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  private void FormatDataSet(DataSet ds) 
{ 
    foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count) 
       dr["Col5"] = (DateTime.Parse(dr["col5"].ToString())).ToString("d").ToString(); 
 }
```

Comment: similar question: [Set DataFormatString on DataGridView at Runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1272771/944681)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is one of the limitations of using the AutoGenerateColumns attribute. Had you defined the columns manually via `BoundField`s, you would be able to control the format with the `DataFormatString` attribute.

As for your case, the reason your approach doesn't work is because you're trying to force a string into a Date type field in the DataSet. This isn't possible unless you change the DataSet definition.

A way around this is to go to the GridView's RowDataBound event and edit the cell manually.

```
private void YourGridViewControl_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = null;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem();
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = (DateTime.Parse(dr("col5").ToString())).ToString("d");
    }
}
```